# TTLauncherView move item to other page

Tags: ios, three20, ttlauncherview

I have a TTLauncherView in my ios app.  I have allowed users to edit and move their items around, however it does not appear that you can move the item from one screen to another, does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: hmm, i was sure that option already existed in the TTLauncherView. I just tried it and it's not working

Answer (score 1):

that's looks like another a bug in three20 library. I just checked an old app of mine and moving items from page to page works fine. It means it might be another iOS 5 issue.

You can open a bug for it in http://github.com/facebook/three20, hopefully someone will fix it.

If I'll get around to it, i'll check it and fix it. I have a few apps using it, so I might need to do that.

Comment: already did, thanks :)

looks like you CAN get it to work, but its definitely got some issues and you have to move the icons just so...

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar problem. It seems to be a bug just for the first icon on that page (i.e. creating a new page) - adding just add another icon to that page works fine (at least for me).
You can get around this bug by dragging the icon to the new page and releasing it on the first row (on the top of the page!). This isn't really satisfying, but perhaps a good starting point.